# NSTextView copy & paste problem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, copy-paste, nstextview

In my application I have an NSTextView. If I want to select some text using the keyboard, I press Command+c, which is supposed to select the text, then Command+v which should paste the selected text. Using the keyboard, it's not working, but using the mouse copy/paste is working.

Moreover, when I type Command+c it invokes the print page -- looks like it's mapped wrongly, but how to correct it ?

Any pointers as to what I need to set to get it handled by the keyboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the various menu items in MainMenu.xib and make sure that all of the equivalent keys are set correctly. Maybe they were changed by accident.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this fixed the problem? Having the same issue here!

Comment: Those keyboard commands are declared in the `NSMenuItem`s in the `NSMenu` in `MainMenu.xib`. `NSMenuItem` has a `keyEquivalent` property that defines the keyboard shortcut that triggers the action on the `NSMenuItem`. These are set by default for the standard items in the menu (like cut, copy, paste, print, etc). If they are changed from the default key-command, the keyboard shortcuts won't work.